# I have a Google Map embedded on my website that I need zoomed out enough to fit all map pins in and still have locations names viewable

Tags: maps, zooming, markers

I have pins on a map of Washington that I need to fit in the view and still have the names of the towns/cities that they are in to show up. When I do this, the pins move off their current position slightly and look as if they are in different locations, until you zoom in and they gradually move back over to their original placement. Also, because its zoomed out, a few of the smaller cities names disappear. I'm not even sure there is a way to keep the names on the screen, but if anyone knows how to it would help muchly.
Here are a few images of my map. You can see how the Bellingham pin looks as if it is in Surrey Canada when zoomed out.

(I couldn't post the images as I need more points and this is the first time I've posted a question here)
Here is some code that may help:

```
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(47.624813, -122.343016);
var myOptions = {
    zoom: 6,
    center: latlng,
    scrollwheel: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
 myOptions);
setMarkers(map, locs);
      }
       var locs = [
['seattle-hq', 47.624813, -122.343016, 4],
['seattle-dist', 47.56075, -122.326426, 5],
['portland', 45.4795312, -122.788215, 3],
['bellingham', 48.7471676, -122.4637092, 2],
['olympia', 47.0391883, -122.8333044, 1],
['spokane', 47.680874, -117.266034, 6],
['tacoma', 47.2430859, -122.3612469, 7],
['tri-cities', 46.20924, -119.216166, 8],
['yakima', 46.572893, -120.528932, 9],
['salem', 44.949672, -122.998292, 10],
['bend', 44.091981, -121.306026, 11],
// ['newidname', 25.197197, 55.2743764, 12]
            ];

          function setMarkers(map, locations) {
// Add markers to the map
var image = {
    url: '/wp- content/themes/copiers_northwest/assets/images/redpin.png',
    // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 32 pixels tall.
        size: new google.maps.Size(35, 45),
    // The origin for this image is 0,0.
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at 0,32.
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(20, 52)
};
var shape = {
    coord: [1, 1, 1, 57, 52, 57, 52, 1],
    type: 'poly'
};
```